# Should a top-voted answer include info "taken" from another answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Prompted by discussion on [this answer's](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/56148/353) comments.

The author of said answer included (with credits and a request to upvote the other) content from another question, with the expressed intent of making said content more visible.

> EDIT: Stealing shamelessly from John Dallman below (please up-vote his answer because it is great)...
>
> - Fingerprints, not even identical twins get identical fingerprints. The same would go for other biological distinguishers, like iris pattern. Although you need to have a print of the original before you try to compare.
> - Antibodies, the immune system contains a historical record of what illnesses you have had, illnesses the clone have not had.
> - Tooth fillings, and/or tooth wear.

In my opinion, it is a useless move because it generates duplicate information on the page.

Then [@Annonymus](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/22383/annonymus) gave this comment, that may have some validity:

> Given that this is currently the topmost answer and some visitors may not read all of the answers they might miss these methods on the original answer if they aren't stated here as well.

At the time of the posting of this meta question, the answer was not topmost anymore. Ironically the other answer that had content copied from was on top.

So, what is the community opinion on this issue?

Comment: The community has voted and it's all come out in the wash

Comment: I think it's ok at least if done on an accepted answer and doesn't really hurt on any other answer either, as long as credit is given where credit is due. But then I already said that.